# Undefined symbol using charlock_holmes gem

Tags: ruby, icu

I installed icu on amazon ec2 with

```
sudo apt-get install libicu-dev
```

Then I installed charlock_holmes:

```
gem install charlock_holmes
```

It seemed to me that it was successfully installed:

```
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
Successfully installed charlock_holmes-0.6.9.4
1 gem installed
```

After that I got this:

```
.../shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/charlock_holmes-0.6.9.4/lib/charlock_holmes.rb:1:in `require':
.../shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/charlock_holmes-0.6.9.4/lib/charlock_holmes/charlock_holmes.so: 
  undefined symbol: _ZN6icu_518ByteSink15GetAppendBufferEiiPciPi   
.../shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/charlock_holmes-0.6.9.4/lib/charlock_holmes/charlock_holmes.so (LoadError)
```

I tried also to install using this command:

```
gem install charlock_holmes -- --with-icu-dir=/usr/local/lib/
```

The error still occures.
It seems to me that somehow I need to specify the right directory `--with-icu-dir`

The reason why I specified `/usr/local/lib` is because the icu libs are installed into that directory.

Comment: I tried to install charlock holmes using this command:

Comment: Downvoter, comments?  Can't see nothing wrong with this question.

Comment: No, this looks like a bug in charlock_holmes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
gem install charlock_holmes -- --with-icu-dir=/usr/local
```

worked for me when I ran into this problem.  The dependencies are smart enough to look up lib for libs, include for header files, and the rest where appropriate under /usr/local.

I got these nasty test errors when installing the gem:

```
unable to convert "\xD0" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for ext/charlock_holmes/dst/bin/file, skipping
unable to convert "\xEE" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for ext/charlock_holmes/src/file-5.08/magic/Magdir/wordprocessors, skipping
unable to convert "\xE5" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for ext/charlock_holmes/src/file-5.08/magic/Magdir/riff, skipping
unable to convert "\xE1" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for ext/charlock_holmes/src/file-5.08/magic/Magdir/linux, skipping
unable to convert "\xE1" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for ext/charlock_holmes/src/file-5.08/magic/Magdir/natinst, skipping
unable to convert "\xBD" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for ext/charlock_holmes/src/file-5.08/magic/Magdir/filesystems, skipping
unable to convert "\xE1" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for ext/charlock_holmes/src/file-5.08/ChangeLog, skipping
unable to convert "\xD0" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for ext/charlock_holmes/src/file-5.08/src/file, skipping
unable to convert "\xCF" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for test/fixtures/hello_world, skipping
```

but they didn't seem to impact my app when running.

Comment: This was the correct command for me:
gem install -i /mnt/searchserverstaging-production/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/ charlock_holmes -- --with-icu-dir=/usr/local