# Can't bundler install

Tags: ruby, rubygems, makefile

I can't `bundler install`, but charlock_holmes.so is installed :

```
root@RoR:/home/git/gitlab# gem install charlock_holmes -v '0.7.1'
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed charlock_holmes-0.7.1
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for charlock_holmes-0.7.1...
Installing RDoc documentation for charlock_holmes-0.7.1...
root@RoR:/home/git/gitlab# bundler install
It's recommended to use Bundler through 'bundle' binary instead of 'bundler'
Fetching source index from https://rubygems.org/
Using rake (10.1.1)
Using ace-rails-ap (2.0.1)
Using i18n (0.6.9)
Using minitest (4.7.5)
Using multi_json (1.8.4)
Using atomic (1.1.14)
Using thread_safe (0.1.3)
Using tzinfo (0.3.38)
Using activesupport (4.0.3)
Using builder (3.1.4)
Using erubis (2.7.0)
Using rack (1.5.2)
Using rack-test (0.6.2)
Using actionpack (4.0.3)
Using mime-types (1.25.1)
Using polyglot (0.3.4)
Using treetop (1.4.15)
Using mail (2.5.4)
Using actionmailer (4.0.3)
Using actionpack-action_caching (1.1.0)
Using actionpack-page_caching (1.0.2)
Using activemodel (4.0.3)
Using activerecord-deprecated_finders (1.0.3)
Using arel (4.0.2)
Using activerecord (4.0.3)
Using bundler (1.5.3)
Using thor (0.18.1)
Using railties (4.0.3)
Using hike (1.2.3)
Using tilt (1.4.1)
Using sprockets (2.10.1)
Using sprockets-rails (2.0.1)
Using rails (4.0.3)
Using acts-as-taggable-on (2.4.1)
Using asciidoctor (0.1.4)
Using descendants_tracker (0.0.3)
Using ice_nine (0.10.0)
Using axiom-types (0.0.5)
Using bcrypt-ruby (3.1.2)
Using sass (3.2.12)
Using bootstrap-sass (3.0.3.0)
Using json (1.8.1)
Using carrierwave (0.9.0)
Using timers (1.1.0)
Using celluloid (0.15.2)

Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb --with-ldflags=-L. -Wl,-O1 -Wl,--as-needed -rdynamic
checking for main() in -licui18n... yes
checking for main() in -licui18n... yes
checking for unicode/ucnv.h... yes
checking for main() in -lz... yes
checking for main() in -licuuc... yes
checking for main() in -licudata... yes
creating Makefile

make
compiling encoding_detector.c
In file included from encoding_detector.c:2:0:
common.h:14:14: warning: ‘charlock_new_enc_str’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
 static VALUE charlock_new_enc_str(const char *str, size_t len, void *encoding)
              ^
compiling ext.c
In file included from ext.c:1:0:
common.h:14:14: warning: ‘charlock_new_enc_str’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
 static VALUE charlock_new_enc_str(const char *str, size_t len, void *encoding)
              ^
common.h:23:14: warning: ‘charlock_new_str’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
 static VALUE charlock_new_str(const char *str, size_t len)
              ^
common.h:32:14: warning: ‘charlock_new_str2’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
 static VALUE charlock_new_str2(const char *str)
              ^
compiling converter.c
In file included from converter.c:2:0:
common.h:23:14: warning: ‘charlock_new_str’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
 static VALUE charlock_new_str(const char *str, size_t len)
              ^
common.h:32:14: warning: ‘charlock_new_str2’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
 static VALUE charlock_new_str2(const char *str)
              ^
compiling transliterator.cpp
In file included from transliterator.cpp:1:0:
common.h:14:14: warning: ‘VALUE charlock_new_enc_str(const char*, size_t, void*)’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
 static VALUE charlock_new_enc_str(const char *str, size_t len, void *encoding)
              ^
common.h:32:14: warning: ‘VALUE charlock_new_str2(const char*)’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
 static VALUE charlock_new_str2(const char *str)
              ^
linking shared-object charlock_holmes/charlock_holmes.so
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libicui18n.a(smpdtfmt.ao): réadressage R_X86_64_PC32 vers symbole « _ZN6icu_5216SimpleDateFormat22isAfterNonNumericFieldERKNS_13UnicodeStringEi » ne peut pas être utilisé en créant un objet partagé ; recompilé avec -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: édition de lien finale en échec: Mauvaise valeur
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [charlock_holmes.so] Erreur 1


Gem files will remain installed in /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/charlock_holmes-0.7.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/charlock_holmes-0.7.1/ext/charlock_holmes/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing charlock_holmes (0.7.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install charlock_holmes -v '0.7.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

No forum have the solution at this problem, can you help me ?

Comment: Have you tried `bundle install`?

Comment: Yes, I tried `bundle install`, same error,
The system is Ubuntu Server 14.04 x64

Comment: I got same problems: https://github.com/brianmario/charlock_holmes/issues/91 :-(

Comment: 1) verify that bundle and gem are from the same ruby: `which gem`, `which bundle`. (They should be the same.) 2) Use `bundle install --local` to force using the one you've already installed locally. (This is just a workaround, `bundle install` should work!)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there is not enough information to reproduce an error, but I think I know what’s going wrong.

`charlock_holmes` itself is not a problem. The problem is introduced by [`libICU`](http://site.icu-project.org/) (`libicui18n.a`::`smpdtfmt.ao`) which appears to be compiled on the target system *without `-fPIC` switch*.

```
[...]/libicui18n.a(smpdtfmt.ao): réadressage R_X86_64_PC32 vers symbole «[...]» 
     ne peut pas être utilisé en créant un objet partagé ; 
     recompilé avec -fPIC
```

I have no clue what’s difference between `bundle install` dependency and direct installation, but to fix an issue I would suggest to do the following:

- remove any `libicu` installed on your system with package manager;
- rebuild the `libicu` package with the flag `-fPIC` *on* (here is [guide for Ubuntu](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/rebuilding-ubuntu-debian-linux-binary-package/));
- install the newly built package;
- retry with `bundle install`.

Hope it helps.

**UPD** Please update the post with version info of `charlock_holmes` as requested by your `gemspec`. Is it smth like `~>0.7.0`, right? My guess is to stuck with the version you have in your gemspec:

```
- 'sharlock_holmes', '~>0.7.0'
+ 'sharlock_holmes', '=0.7.0'
```

Comment: In my own case, I solve it in heroku using custom buildpack. Now the gem can be installed and used in heroku. I suspect the same, the libicu in the trusty that have the problems. What strange is that the same library could be used fine last year.

Comment: @DonnyKurnia `libICU` itself is fine. Here the problem is in interoperation. **Just realized, that rolling back to previous version of sherlock might fix the problem as well.**. `sherlock_holmes` apparently has been having [problems with libicu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16716678/undefined-symbol-using-charlock-holmes-gem), I bet there should be some [unknown] circumstances for the bug to reproduce.

Answer (score 0):

Seems bundler needs to be configured differently to install `charlock_holmes` gem. Try the following:

`bundle config build.charlock_holmes --with-icu-dir=/path/to/installed/icu4c`

Excerpt from `charlock_holmes` gem [README](https://github.com/brianmario/charlock_holmes#installing):

> If the traditional gem install charlock_holmes doesn't work, you may
>   need to specify the path to your installation of ICU using the
>   --with-icu-dir option during the gem install or by configuring Bundler to pass those arguments to Gem.